# LATEX: How to represent root(2)^root(2)

Tags: math-mode

In latex, how would one represent `\math{sqrt{2} ^ sqrt{2}}`  (or `root(2)^root(2)`? I tried to respresent it as I did above, but there is an error "! Missing { inserted."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[ \sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2}}}\]
  \[ \bigl(\sqrt{2}\bigr)^{\sqrt{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make them inline, use $ instead of `\[...\]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[ \sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2}}}\]
  $ \sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2}}}}}$ or $ \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would one do root(2) ^ root(2) ^ root(2)? And also how would one have that text not centered on the page. I am looking to make the sentence: Let x be \[ (\sqrt{2})^{(\sqrt{2})}^{\sqrt{2}}   \]

Comment: @Jim Please see the update.

Comment: @Jim You are welcome. Thanks can be conveyed through upvoting (once you get 15 rep points) and accepting the most useful answer. This is the tradition followed here. For details please see:  [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Comment: The notation `$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$` is commonly used (without parentheses).

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Had a little doubt, hence that `or`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or...........

$2^{1/\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: While they're equivalent, that's not really the question being asked. :)